# how do I add a comma after the 1st number for thousandths?

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon!
I have created a function that simulates counting numbers.
As a result, I got a number without commas.

My result: [image]

What I want to get:[image]

I need to add a comma for thousandths, as in the example above.

code

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#count-up-number');
  let time = 5;

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.textContent = '0';

    const updateCount = () => {
      const number = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-value'));
      const value = +element.textContent;

      const increment = number / 200;
      if (value < number) {
        element.textContent = `${Math.ceil(value + increment)}`;
        setTimeout(updateCount, time);
      }
    }
    updateCount();
  })
```

```html
 <span class="card-number" id="count-up-number" data-value="2495">2,495</span>
```

Comment: Checkout [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Comment: Query selector all with an id selector doesn't really make sense, because element id values must be unique across a document. You'll get a list of zero or one elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intl.NumberFormat` and `toLocaleString` are both possible solutions as the other answers pointed out. My answer therefore focuses on how we could implement this in a more "do-yourself" fashion:

```js
var str = '9012345678';
while (str.length % 3) str = '0' + str;
console.log(str.match(/.{1,3}/g).map((x, i) => i ? x : parseInt(x)).join(","));
```

Explanation:

- if we have a number, we need to convert it to string, because we are speaking about strings representing formatted numbers
- we prepend 0roes at the start of our string until it's divisible with 3 to avoid a comma before the last or penultimate digit
- we cut our string into sections of 3 characters with the help of a regular expression
- we `.map` our chunks into themselves, except for the first one, which we map to its integer correspondent to get rid of preceding 0roes
- we `.join(",")` our chunks to get the format we intended to have

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by converting the number to locale string.

```js
const number = 2496;

const formattedNumber = number.toLocaleString("en-US");

console.log(formattedNumber); // 2,496
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) will handle this and also deal with countries that use a `.` as a thousands separator and other regional variations.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number);
```

The default with no specific options specified will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Don't suggest Intl.NumberFormat, it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working correctly?

Comment: There is a number 3,675. This is the expected result. If I use Intl.NumberFormat, I get 1,008 instead of 3,675.

Comment: That's a secondary problem. You now reading back the current value as a string `'1,008'` and `+value` will return NaN and cause an error in your code. I'd recommend storing the count value on a data attribute like the final value during each iteration, without the international formatting.

Comment: This is why I don't use Intl.NumberFormat.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) will handle this and also deal with countries that use a `.` as a thousands separator and other regional variations.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number);
```

The default with no specific options specified will do exactly what you want for formatting.

However, this will break the existing implementation where you're using `+element.textContent` to read back the currently displayed value. Once you reach a value > 1000 it will not be able to parse the value any more because of the comma. You can work around this by storing the un-formatted value in an attribute on the element.

Note the html was also modified to set a default value of zero for `data-count`. You could also put a `=== undefined` condition in the `updateCount()` function to do the same during a cold-start.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#count-up-number');
  let time = 5;

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.textContent = '0';

    const updateCount = () => {
      const number = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-value'));
      const value = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-count'));

      const increment = number / 200;
      if (value < number) {
        const newValue = Math.ceil(value + increment);
        element.setAttribute('data-count', newValue);
        element.textContent = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(newValue);
        setTimeout(updateCount, time);
      }
    }
    updateCount();
  })
```

```html
 <span class="card-number" id="count-up-number" data-value="2495" data-count="0">2,495</span>
```